# facebook chatbot with international payment

Tags: facebook-graph-api, botframework, facebook-chatbot

I am developing Facebook chatbot using .NET Microsoft bot framework and there is a requirement that bot allows user to buy products online and it needs to be worldwide. I have checked [Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/payments) but it seems like the only option to integrate payment internationally is to use Custom Implementation in the Messenger Webview and open existing website that already has checkout process? but I have seen some chatbots eg. Hijiffy Hotel booking chatbot can do payment worldwide on messenger itself as picture below? How is it possible? I am quite new to this and maybe I have misunderstood.

Thanks a lot.

[Hijiffy features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNKJO.png)

Comment: your `Hijiffy` sample seems to be built with another technology than Microsoft Bot Framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screenshot appears to implement a custom payment flow in the webview. What you are likely seeing there is the webview opened with `webview_height_ratio: 'tall'`.

The Messenger webview opens external websites, but does so within the Messenger app, so to you end user the flow never actually leaves Messenger.